# Rspec - Inconsistent let behavior

Tags: rspec

Can someone explain this to me?

```
describe 'test some stuff' do

  let (:dude) {"where's my var"}
  let (:container) do {} end

  it 'does some stuff' do
    puts dude
    container[:dude] = dude
    puts container
  end

  it 'does some other stuff' do
    puts dude
    puts container
  end
end
```

outputs

```
where's my var
{:dude=>"where's my var"}
where's my var
{}
```

Why does the :dude variable (which is a string) evaluate across it blocks, but the :container variable (which is a hash) does not?

I need one example to store a result for use in another example.  What is the preferred method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Having thought about this a bit more, it makes sense.  When you declare a variable using let that contains an empty hash, that variable is going to get lazily initialized whenever it is called, just like any other variable defined with let.  Just because you populate the empty hash in one example, doesn't mean that variable gets updated or redefined.  When the next example calls that variable, it initializes as it was defined, and empty hash.

As far as a best practice for sharing data across examples, I've ended up using a before block with a @test_data={} defined.  I then populate that hash with the data I need from one example to make available across examples.  Don't know if this is preferred or acceptable.  Would welcome alternative suggestions.